# Set an input field within a form, within a frame using javascript in a UWP project

Tags: javascript, c#, uwp

I am trying to autofill a form that is located within a frame.  There appears to be a syntax error in the javascript.  Any help with the function would be appreciated.  Here is the code I am using;

```
string func = "window.frames['framename'].document.forms[0].getElementsByName('StreetName')[0].value = " + streetname;

await webview1.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { func });
```

The id of the tags is not set, only the names.  Any ideas where the syntax error in the JS is?

p.s. If there is a way to get the verbose error message from the injected javascript I would welcome the advice.

Answer (score 1):

```
'framename'
```

is highly suspect to me.

Are you sure that is intended to be a string literal?  (In that case, I think this is a runtime error and not a syntax error).